# Launch activity from widget and then back to widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-activity

I've an desktop widget, and inside it I have a settings button - when tap it, I launch an activity, where I can change widget settings. An activity is very simple, it has only few spinner, checkboxes, etc. and 2 button - OK and CANCEL.

And the biggest problem for me is, that I know how to launch activity from widget, but don't know how to "go back" to widget from activity - the only possible way is press the back button on the phone. But as u can see, I really need to have 2 buttons - OK and Cancel, as its looks much more natural for the user. What method I should use after pressing OK/Cancel button to turn an activity to background and widget to foreground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   in onclicklistener of ok button call finish()
```